# Diffrence between running task manually and automatically in Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, taskscheduler

I have huge problem, and I don't know what heppend with my task in Task Scheduler in Windows 2012 R2

Task, has no working since few weeks, Same task in other server works fine.

When task run automatically it's not work, but in log I have information that is done without error, when I run same task manually (using Run on this task in TaskScheduler) then this work fine,

Where is the problem?
Someone can help me? Or suggest how to fix it or where looking the rootcasue of this problem?

Comment: how you came to know task was not run successfully?

Comment: it is task to anonimize logs files, so when task is ran automatically, it's not create a file

Comment: this might be issue with directory access, to check it give full previlages to everyone user and try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found where the problem was

When script it ran, file not exist in file directory, and that is the reason. When someone came to job at morning, and run the application file it created, and then manually run the task, task find the file.